# Basics of Set Theory : complement of an intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, propositional-calculus

My maths textbook says,

1) If x ∉ (A∩B)

> => *x ∉ A **or** x ∉ B*

2) If, A = {x:x is divisible by 3 and 5}

> => *A' = {x:x is not divisible by 3 **or** x is not divisible by 5}*

The italicised parts are troubling me. I am unable to visualise them or even comprehend them, especially the contextual meaning of the word "**or**" used in them. Please help me to understand these statements.

Comment: "not ($p$ and $q$)" is equivalent to "not $p$ **or** not $q$"

Comment: Maybe this (https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8f/b1/79/8fb1796ad5ab605a0db350f010e27161--logic-math-logic-puzzles.jpg) graphic can help you to visualize the statements

Comment: In mathematics, unless otherwise stated, "or" always means the _inclusive or_.  That is, "$p$ or $q$" by default means "at least one of $p,q$ is true".  In this light, there isn't any contextual problems for "or".

Comment: If $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$ are **both** true, then $x$ will belong to **both**. Thus, if not, at least one of them must be false.

Comment: In mathematics "not-A or not-B" means that A and B cannot both be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The intersection of a set $A$ and of a set $B$ , namely the set $A\cap B$ , is defined using the logical operator " and " ( symbol : $\land$)

$A\cap B$ is the set of all objects that belong both to A and to B :

$A\cap B= \{x| x \in A \land x\in B\}$

- Consequently, in order to define the complement of the set $A\cap B  $ we need to know what is the negation of an and-statement. And  DeMorgan's law tells us that

"it is not the case that both sentence $P$ and sentence $Q$ are true"

is equivalent to

" either $P$ is false OR $Q$ is false".

Saying that " Peter is not  both a pianist and a guitarist"  means that " either Peter is not a pianist OR Peter is not a guitarist".

Note : you can check using a truth table that DeMorgan's law is actually a logical equivalence.

- If we apply this *inside* the set builder notation, with

$A$ = the set of all $x$ such that $3$ divides x

$B$= the set of all $x$ such that $5$ divides $x$ ,

we get :

$(A\cap B)'$

= the set of all $x$ that do *NOT* belong both to$ A$ and to $B$.

$ = \{x| \neg (3|x \land  5|x)\}$

$ = \{x| \neg (3|x) \lor \neg (5|x)\}$

Answer (score 1):

We also know that $(P \implies Q) \iff (\lnot Q \implies \lnot P)$. Say that it is **not** true that either $x \not \in A$ **or** $x \not \in B$. Then $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$. Then $x \in A \cap B$. Therefore $x \not \in (A \cap B) \implies (x \not \in A \lor x \not \in B)$.

Now in this particular case, say that it is **not** true that $x$ is divisible by both $3$ **and** $5$. Then $x$ is either not divisible by $3$ **or** not divisible by $5$ (or both).

Comment: You're welcome.